# Alpine Linux: Disable switching into framebuffer mode at boot?

Tags: alpine-linux, framebuffer

We are installing a custom version of Alpine Linux on several embedded elderly PC.  The monitor is connected using VGA and may not report the supported resolutions correctly, hence the GPU may choose a resolution larger than supported by the monitor, resulting in only a part of the display area being shown to the user.

This happens when Alpine Linux switches into framebuffer mode during the boot sequence.  We would like to postpone that, so the question is

> How to disable switching into framebuffer mode on the console during boot on Alpine Linux?

Comment: Could the [`vga=` option](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) in the kernel parameters solve the situation?

Comment: Suggestion from IRC:  "nofb" in /etc/update-extlinux.conf, the APPEND section